# Strange java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown on jetty startup

Tags: java, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Whenever I deploy jetty application I hit this issue. Looks like some `jar` or class is broken.

- Colleagues compiling exactly same code, doesn't hit the issue. Even if the deploy to the same computer. (we use `git` and `maven`)
- Deleting local maven repository `~/.m2` and rebuilding doesn't help.
- Can run same jetty app locally without any issues.
- My initial suspect was that some `jar` is broken. Tried `jar tvf $every_jar` and haven't found anything.

Any ideas how can I debug this? Looks really mysterious and I suspect is that some file get corrupted.

```
Stack trace:
2014-10-21 13:29:25.123:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/XYZ/},/XYZ/webapps/root
javax.servlet.ServletException: jersey-serlvet
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:553)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

followed by

```
Caused by:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6241
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:223)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
```

Answer (score 28):

For your 2 errors ..

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: jersey-serlvet
```

This means you have a typo in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`

As for this one ..

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6241
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I've seen similar ones when using an old version of `asm.jar` with newer compiled Java bytecode.

- For Java 15 bytecode, use **asm 7.3.1+**
- For Java 14 bytecode, use **asm 7.2+**
- For Java 13 bytecode, use **asm 7.1+**
- For Java 12 bytecode, use **asm 7.1+**
- For Java 11 bytecode, use **asm 7.0+**
- For Java 10 bytecode, use **asm 6.1+**
- For Java 9 bytecode, use **asm 6.0+**
- For Java 8 bytecode, use **asm 5.0.1+**
- For Java 6 or Java 7 bytecode, (Use **asm 3.1** if you must, but know that **asm 5.x** is also going to work here too)

Ensure that your `asm.jar` (or `org.objectweb.asm.jar`) is current.

There is a slightly less common issue where the class itself is bad.  Sometimes seen with classes that are compiled in one JDK (such as IBM) and then run on another Java (like Sun/Oracle).

A real world example of this would be [the `icu4j-2.6.1.jar` and its `com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class` jar entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38831984/775715).

Comment: Use Java 7 and asm 3.1.

Comment: What you use for your JVM is irrelevant to bytecode scanning, the class that is causing the failure could be of a bytecode higher than your JVM. (in other words, the class that is being tripped up could be compiled for Java 8)

Comment: The features that are not handled by ASM 3, are already defined in Java 7 and even if `javac` doesn’t use them, you might encounter them at runtime. There’s no sense in recommending using an outdated version anyway. Just use ASM 5 for *all* versions…

Comment: I don't use asm library. It happens with Android Studio. And only with release build variant, debug is built fine

Comment: @user155 bytecode scanning with `asm` on android should not work. as the bytecode isn't java anymore when on Android.

Comment: I was using asm3.1 in Java8 with no problems until I used Java8-specific classes. In my case it was `java.util.stream.Stream`. Removing that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Use newer version of jetty-maven-plugin.

More information --> [Bug 419801 - Upgrade to asm5 for jdk8](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419801)

So, edit your `pom.xml` like this：

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.M2</version>
</plugin>
```

Note the groupId is "**org.eclipse.jetty**".

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me! See available [jetty-maven-plugin versions](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin) in Maven Central.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I am using ASM library version and that not support java 8 lambda expression, so either you change ASM library to support java 8 or change your code.

In my case I am using java 8 lambda expression for iterating and I replaced it with for loop

Comment: I got this problem when I added `java.util.stream.Stream` and fixed it by removing it.

Answer (score 2):

I came across similar issue when maintaining legacy code.

```
Servlet.init() for servlet JerseyServlet threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet JerseyServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet JerseyServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.65 logs.
```

I fixed it with reducing the package scanning scope in web.xml. E.g., removing the package_with_too_many_classes below in param-value tag fixed the issue.

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>package_with_too_many_classes;package_with_approciate_number_of_classes;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

Comment: This worked in my case. I had added new non-servlet classes in a sub-package. I changed their package path and the errors went away.